# How is random sampling done in practical terms with a large population (e.g,. people suffering from arthritis in the US)?

Tags: sampling

my first post here. I'm studying statistics and we are learning about random sampling but I don't understand how what I am learning is applicable to the real world. Are there stat books or articles that explain how this is done? I mean if I need to pick 10 randomly out of 200 people I know (e.g., in a class), random sampling is fairly easy. I could give everyone a number and use some random number generation system and pick 10 of them. Of course, if the first 10 refuse and I pick another 10, I could compare the two on important data relevant to my study (assuming I have such info on them) to see if my random sample is a good sample.

However, I know every little about all American people with, say, arthritis. How do I randomly sample them? And what if some say no? How do I know my sample is not biased (e.g., made up of the most motivated or people who are suffering with the most pain?)

I appreciate you helping me.

Comment: Some excellent discussion of these and related issues appears in the first two (short) chapters of *Statistics* by Freedman *et al.*  They are available at https://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Fourth-David-Freedman-ebook/dp/B00SLB5Q72.

Comment: Okay, I will try to find the book...

Comment: Used copies are readily available.  (Long ago I learned stats from the first edition, purchased for \$0.25 in a remainder bin.)